# How to append data to existing xml file using Python

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing

I have to add a new line like ./dir/pqr in the <filename sections to the following existing xml file. The 'url' is a link

```
<dbchangelog
    xmlns="http://url/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
    xmlns:xsi="http://url/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://url/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://url/xml/ns/dbchangelog-4.1.xsd">
    <changeSet author="name" id="v3.0.0">
        <tagDatabase tag="release/v3.0.0" />
    </changeSet>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <path>
                <filename>./dir/commons</filename>
            </path>
            <path>
                <filename>./dir/abc</filename>
            </path>
            <path>
                <filename>./dir/xyz</filename>
            </path>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
</dbchangelog>
```

Tried following piece of code, it prints the appended value but doesn't actually append to the file.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET 
tree = ET.parse('pqr.xml')
root = tree.getroot() 
b = ET.SubElement(root, 'filename')
b.text = './dml/release/v3.0.0/abc_changelog.xml' 
print ET.tostring(root)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python elementtree xml append](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31631525/python-elementtree-xml-append)

Comment: No, it doesn't. probably because the xml structure is different. I have found multiple answers but none woks for the said xml file

Comment: Please share a valid xml example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to register the Namespace and insert than the attribute instead text:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('pqr.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

# Register the Namespace
ns = {'': 'http://url/xml/ns/dblogs', 'xsi': 'http://url/2001/XMLSchema-instance', 'pro': 'http://url/xml/ns/dblogs/ns/pro'}
for key, value in ns.items():
    ET.register_namespace(key, value)

# Set attribute value instead of text
b = ET.SubElement(root, 'include')
b.attrib['file'] = './dml/release/v3.0.0/abc_changelog.xml'

ET.indent(root, space='  ')
ET.dump(root)

# Write the result to a new file:
tree = ET.ElementTree(root)
ET.indent(tree, space='  ')
tree.write("out_new.xml", xml_declaration=True, encoding='UTF-8')
```

Output:

```
<dblogs xmlns="http://url/xml/ns/dblogs" xmlns:xsi="http://url/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://url/xml/ns/dblogs">
  <changeSet author="user_id" id="v3.0.0">
    <tagDatabase tag="release/v3.0.0" />
  </changeSet>
  <include file="./file_one.xml" />
  <include file="./file_two.xml" />
  <include file="./dml/release/v3.0.0/abc_changelog.xml" />
</dblogs>
```

Comment: But when i open the pqr.xml, I don't see any new line added, though it's displayed in the output

Comment: How do I read the xmlns value while parsing the xml file ? The output must be http://url/xml/ns/dblogs

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a closing " in the following line:

> xsi:schemaLocation="http://url/xml/ns/dblogs >

When adding this your code works for me with following output:

`b'<ns0:dblogs xmlns:ns0="http://url/xml/ns/dblogs" xmlns:ns1="http://url/2001/XMLSchema-instance" ns1:schemaLocation="http://url/xml/ns/dblogs">\n\n    <ns0:changeSet author="user_id" id="v3.0.0">\n\n        <ns0:tagDatabase tag="release/v3.0.0" />\n\n    </ns0:changeSet>\n\n    <ns0:include file="./file_one.xml" />\n\n    <ns0:include file="./file_two.xml" />\n\n<include>./dml/release/v3.0.0/abc_changelog.xml</include></ns0:dblogs`

notice that in your code the tag is added as:

`<include>./dml/release/v3.0.0/abc_changelog.xml</include>`

To make it appear in the same manner as the others you also have to include the namespace ([Emitting namespace specifications with ElementTree in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4997848/emitting-namespace-specifications-with-elementtree-in-python)) and the file argument ([How do I add attributes to SubElement in ElementTree (Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25807414/how-do-i-add-attributes-to-subelement-in-elementtree-python))

Comment: You lost the namespace declaration.